# Launch a Windows Application on Windows Startup with some delay without UAC

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer

Wants to Launch a Windows Application(developed in C#,WPF) on Windows Startup with 5 Minutes of delay mean it should wait for 5 min when OS boot & then launch the Windows Application.

Window Application needs **administrator privileges** to launch it. So it always give the **UAC prompt** when user start it by double click . So it is fine But I want when the Application run on Windows Startup with some delay & **it should not show the UAC prompt**

[UAC Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E22nA.png)

The Application is developed in c# & installed using MSI.

The Application also has windows service running at background & can help in launching the Application with delay but how to hide the UAC prompt or any other better idea to launch Application with delay.

**So any suggestion how to do it with c# or by changing the settings of MSI.**

Answer (score 2):

you have to create windows task scheduler for this. It will satisfied your both requirement.

> Create windows task scheduler (Manual)

- Goto Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Task Scheduler
- In Action Menu
- Crete Basic Task
- Name of your task as you want and click next
- Select "When I log on" and click next
- Select "Start a program" and click next
- Browse of your application path and click next
- Finish
- Select your task in Task Scheduler Library with name of your task
- double click on it.
- in General tab check the checkbox of "run with highest privileges"  for 
  remove UAC prompt

> Create windows task scheduler (Using C#)

you can also create windows task scheduler using c#

you have to download library (nuget) from https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler/

code reference http://asphelps.com/Asp.Net/TaskScheduler.aspx